# Will a 30 mA RCCB trip if the differential current is less than 30 mA?

Tags: rcd

All available literature states that an RCD trips whenever there is imbalance between the currents flowing through the Live and Neutral wires.

But does it need to be higher than the labelled value?

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the spec, there ought to be two values, a minimum and a maximum. Below the minimum it will definitely not trip. Above the maximum it will definitely trip.

Answer (score 0):

The test button on an RCD works, even if there is no load on RCD.

So no load current is needed.

if neutral wire has 0mA flowing and test button causes a 30mA test current to flow in live wire, it will trip.

Comment: This answer could be misleading, given the test button introduces a load current.

Comment: @toxicantidote Test button does not introduce a load current in the protected circuit as it would flow between protected neutral and protected live wires. Test button introduces fault current, which means one of the protected wires have more current flowing than the other wire, thus creating differential current of about 30mA.

Comment: With that additional explanation, I think I better understand what you were trying to say - When the test button is pushed, a 30mA current flows from the live protected wire to the neutral unprotected wire.

Comment: @toxicantidote maybe, or from live unprotected wire to protected neutral. Depends on implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Since an RCD is a safety device, I expect it is required to trip with 30 mA or more fault current.  To ensure this, most units will trip at somewhat less than 30 mA.

Answer (score 0):

An RCD should trip before it reaches the rated residual (differential) current. It should not trip at half the rated residual current.